# Is it possible to configure nginx to just handle SSL?

Tags: nginx, ssl, fastcgi

I have a web server written in C++ already, but it uses TCP sockets without SSL.  I want to connect it to the web, but I want to use something like nginx to handle the SSL, and also basic security like DDOS protection, smurf attack protection, etc.

My question is, can I set up nginx to handle the secure SSL connection, and forward unencrypted http traffic to my web server (on the same machine)?

I feel like this could be a simpler alternative to setting up my application to interface with nginx via FastCGI.

(Any other suggestions, please feel free to suggest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

1. Make your own software listen on *local loopback* alone, e.g. on `localhost:8080`.
2. [*Terminate* TLS](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/) with NGINX.

   ```
   server { 
       listen 443 ssl; 
       server_name www.example.com;
       ssl_certificate www.example.com.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key; 
       ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
       ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5; 
       #... 
   }
   ```
3. As a best practice, redirect HTTP to HTTPS and enable [HSTS](https://www.nginx.com/blog/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-and-nginx/) for client-side upgrade to encrypted connection.

   ```
   server { 
       listen 80;
       server_name example.com;
       return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; 
   }

   server { 
       listen 443 ssl;
       #... 
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
       #...
   }
   ```
4. Configure NGINX as [*reverse proxy*](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/), e.g.

   ```
       location / { 
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/; 
       }
   ```

Comment: Thanks.  And can I configure SSL certificates and whatnot for the main hosted domain through nginx?

Comment: Yes. That's within the basic functionality of a web server.

Comment: Of course, I know that nginx can do that, I just wasn't sure that it can separate the encryption part and pass the unsecure request to the proxy, rather than attempt to pass the request in its entirety to the unsecure http server.

Comment: I've updated my answer to also cover this.

Comment: One note, make sure you get the cipher list correct as most ciphers out here are considered unsecure. I personally like the Mozilla ciphers lists (https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS), but OWASP has some good ones as well. Also, TLS 1.3 is also quite standard these days.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!